# SQLite выдаёт не верный результат

Tags: android, sqlite

Есть таблица в которой хранятся записи месяцев.

```
CREATE TABLE months (
_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
name TEXT,
paid INTEGER DEFAULT '0',
FOREIGN KEY (_id) REFERENCES clients (_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

В таблице есть записи с названиями месяцев(january,february,march and etc). Все поля Paid равны 0.
Такой запрос SQLiteBrowser(и на телефоне с Android 5) вернёт 1ый месяц january(как они были добавлены). На телефоне с 4.3 1ый месяц уже вернёт april(1ый по алфавиту). В чем проблема?

```
SELECT * FROM months WHERE name = (SELECT name FROM months WHERE paid = 0 LIMIT 1);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том что в реляционной алгебре нет понятия сортировки, с соответственно не определено понятие "первый".
А так как SQL основан на ней, в нем также понятие "первый" не определено пока не указана явная сортировка в секции ORDER BY

> SELECT * FROM months WHERE name = january; - почему-то возвращает april

Это физически невозможно.

Фраза "понятие первый не определено" означает что один и тот же запрос в одинаковых с виду условиях может вернуть разный результат, отличающийся сортировкой.

И если вы не поняли намеков скажу явно - при использовании ограничения по количеству записей в выводе предложение ORDER BY является обязательным!

PS объясните пожалуйста, зачем тут подзапрос?

Comment: Поставлю вопрос по другому.
SELECT name FROM months WHERE paid = 0 LIMIT 1 - Возвращается january на любой версии SQLite. И если перефразировать то такой запрос
SELECT * FROM months WHERE name = january; - почему-то возвращает april

Comment: Опишу свою задачу. Мне нужно при обновлении поля(из другой таблицы) срабатывал запрос который обновляет таблицу months месяцы по порядку. 
Например january paid - 1
потом february paid - 1 и т.д.
Для всего этого у меня есть триггер который срабатывает и должен обновлять месяцы. И получается такая ситуация что на компе(триггер) у меня всё отлично срабатывает, ставлю на телефон он обновляет но только месяцы по алфавиту а не так как я их добавил. Быть может есть идеи как это можно решить?

Comment: Добавить поле - номер месяца и использовать сортировку по нему. `(SELECT name FROM months WHERE paid = 0 ORDER BY num LIMIT 1)`